# CORS problems with Angular 4 and JHipster

Tags: angular, jhipster

i'm new on Angular4 and Jhipster and i'm facing a cors error

> Failed to load https://www.google.com/: Redirect from 'https://www.google.com/' to 'https://www.google.fr/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=1jd0WqijGqbC8geHkYWgAQ' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

while i try

```
const link = 'http://www.google.com';
this.http.get(link).map(res => res).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data.toString());
    return data.toString();
});
```

Can anyone help please ?

Comment: CORS issues are usually a server configuration issue. If you're using the correct URL, Angular can't do anything about it. CORS is only about browser and the server.

Comment: CORS is handled on the backend as for permissions on, for example, REST endpoints. Likely, Google.com does not allow it.

Comment: Thanx guys for your answer.<br/> So, what's the appropriate way to extract data from a web page? <br/> I want to do something like facebook does when we specify a url in post. <br/> thnx in advance

Answer (score -2):

i don't know about jhipster. 
However your HTTP Server have to add:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true'
```

Into the HTTP Header. Origin is the site from which you access (your Anuglar-side). Methods are the HTTP Functions you use. 
More about cors you find on [Mozilla Dev](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)
best wishes